# How to getType from a reference dll when copylocal property is false

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, c#-2.0

I need to make something like:

```
Type CustomType = Type.GetType("instanceName");
```

It always returns null. instanceName is a string which represents a type contained in a dll added to References (with copyLocal property set to false).

I also tried:

```
Type CustomType = Type.GetType("instanceName, dllFile.dll");
```

But also returns null.

Thanks a lot

Alex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the assembly is already loaded you could try this:

```
Type customType = Type.GetType("namespace.typename, assembly");
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are not deploying the assembly to the GAC and the `CopyLocal` setting is set to `false`, then where are you planning to load the assembly from?

If you are planning to deploy the assemblies to a fixed location on a drive, you can use `Assembly.LoadFrom`:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Path\To\Assembly.dll");
var type = assembly.GetType("InstanceName");
```

This allows you to load an absolute assembly. If you are using `Type.GetType`, it uses the standard fusion assembly loading rules to attempt to find a matching assemby (but if it is not GAC'd or `CopyLocal` = `true`), then it won't be deployed with your output, and `GetType` will return null.

Also, if you do not specify an assembly name in the type name, e.g. `instanceName, assemblyName`, instead of `instanceName`, the I *believe* only the currently executing assembly is checked.

Comment: thanks, is not exactly what I was searching but its a good solution :)